# Use Python to output bold text in .doc

Tags: python, printing, format

I am trying to print this statement:

```
a= 'Hi %s, \n The meeting is scheduled for %s %sth \n if you have an  questions please contact %s' % (cfname, meetingmonth, meetingday, cleadfname)
print a
```

I'm also trying to bold every variable insert (i.e. cfname, meetingmonth etc.). Basically, I have a script asking the enduser for input which writes this statement to a .doc format. Is there a simple way to bold things when writing something in python?

I've tried the bold brackets around the word  and that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be great!

Comment: What is your output medium?

Comment: its a document called read.doc

Comment: Why are you using `print` instead of a library for writing Word files?

Comment: not positive...I am a beginner here....I could also have it write to a txt file

Comment: There's no way to indicate bold text in a plain text file.

Comment: so if I did it in a doc file is there a way to do it a python library you can point me to that I could implement in the program?

Comment: There are several ways to generate a Word document. The easiest (but most restricted) way would be to drive Word using COM, which would require both Windows and a copy of Word. Next would be using PyUno to drive around OpenOffice or LibreOffice, which would require one of them to be installed. Smallest and most open would be to use python-docx to generate a .docx file directly.

Comment: Unless you're using an ancient version of Word, you can simply add HTML tags to your string, give the resulting file a `.doc` extension, and then open the file in Word as normal (see answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` produces plain text, not Microsoft Word documents. If you add HTML formatting tags (`<html>`, `<body>`, `<strong>`, `<br />`, etc.) where necessary, then give the resulting text file the `.doc` extension, it will open with Word, which - assuming you have a reasonably recent version that understands HTML - will parse the HTML and display the result you're looking for.

Sample:

```
a= '<html><head></head><body>Hi %s, </br> The meeting is scheduled for <strong>%s %sth</strong> <br /> if you have an  questions please contact %s</body></html>' % (cfname, meetingmonth, meetingday, cleadfname)
```

Answer (score 1):

try using [termcolor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor)

```
>>> from termcolor import cprint
>>> cprint("Hello", attrs=['bold'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have some success with a module that helps python output Rich Text Format, like [PyRTF](http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0LEVij4xwxV05sA8h43nIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByMG04Z2o2BHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2JmMQR2dGlkAw--/RV=2/RE=1426929784/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2fpyrtf.sourceforge.net%2f/RK=0/RS=dD2YgZhis257TWRmFyY316DSmv0-).

However, it has been suggested that HTML is easier to work with:

[Fonts formatting in python output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108930/fonts-formatting-in-python-output)