# Insert boolean in RTF file using java

Tags: java, rtf

I have no idea how can I insert boolean sign into RTF document from java programm. I think about √ or ✓ and –. I tried insert these signs to clear document and save it as *.rtf and then open it in Notepad++ but there is a lot of codes (~160 lines) and I can not understand what is it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You may want [this specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725). I pity you.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [RTF](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)

√ or ✓ and – are not available in every charset, so specify it. If yout output in UTF-8 (and i advise you to do so, check here [on how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java)). You might need to encode the sign aswell, check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark)

Answer (score -1):

After a short search I found this:

[Writing unicode to rtf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894772/writing-unicode-to-rtf-file)

So a final code version would be:

```
public void writeToFile() {

    String strJapanese = "日本語✓";

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.rtf");
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
        out.write(strJapanese);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```